# Избавиться от NULL в LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Даже, если нет данных в таблицах, возвращает `NULL`, как избавиться от этого?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(l.LogId) AS CNT,
  l.LogStatus,
  s.SubscrubeToUsersType
FROM
  subscrubetousers s
LEFT JOIN
  log l
ON
  l.LogType = s.SubscrubeToUsersType AND
  s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = l.logIdUser AND
  l.LogStatus = 0
WHERE
  s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = 65 AND
  s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Не знаю, что значит NULL в вашем вопросе, но попробуйте вместо "IS NOT NULL" использовать "NOT ISNULL(`field_name`)"

Comment: is not null вполне нормальная конструкция.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избавиться от null в left join стоит убрать left join и поставить inner join.
В вашем случае на null надо проверять поля пристыковываемой таблицы, то есть l.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af5c22/2

Comment: Что-то не помог ваш inner join:

SELECT COUNT( l.LogId ) AS CNT, l.LogStatus, s.SubscrubeToUsersType
FROM subscrubetousers s
INNER JOIN log l ON ( l.LogType = s.SubscrubeToUsersType
AND s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = l.logIdUser
AND l.LogStatus =0 ) 
WHERE s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser =65
AND s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser IS NOT NULL

Comment: Обновил. Ловите

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось делать так:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(l.LogId) AS CNT,
  l.LogStatus,
  s.SubscrubeToUsersType
FROM
  subscrubetousers s
INNER JOIN
  log l
ON
  l.LogType = s.SubscrubeToUsersType AND
  s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = l.logIdUser AND
  l.LogStatus = 0
WHERE
  s.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = 65
HAVING
  CNT > 0
```